# Huge size log file in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, logfile

I have SQL database and I have sent the same database to other place for further development (there may be or may not changes in Schema). I created a a backup file and restored it on another SQL Server.

I found the log file size is very huge (14GB) even though I only have 4 tables with 1000 rows and will not grow two much. Currently I run query and found (Size is in MB).

```
 data_size  data_used_size  log_size    log_used_size
 801.00     2.06            14220.75    55.63
```

---

**What I did:**

I have shrunk the log files using SQL Management Studio and also kept **SIMPLE** mode recovery, as we have only few updates to this database that can be done again if transaction fails at any point. I created a backup and restored same and found size of log file has decreased considerably and here is here under.

```
 total_size data_size   data_used_size  log_size    log_used_size
 802.00     801.00      2.06            1.00         0.46
```

---

- Question 1: Since the database size very less should we decrease the initial size of database
- Question 2: Is this ok now to send this .bak file for restoring database at another location

Comment: Is storage a concern? What pain are you trying to fix?

Comment: Question 1 - There's little harm in dropping the initial size and making a small size increment if you think that the DB is going to grow very slowly - otherwise you have empty space sitting around reserved for nothing - it's up to you - empty disk space is also doing nothing, if you have 100 DB's likely to grow to 1 GB  over time, is it better to reserve in advance or not reserve and see the disk space start to disappear over time? Your call  Question 2: You should be able to restore from the .bak at another location - with databases, it's best to check that this can be achieved as a trial.

Comment: log file may not grow as much in simple model, it depends why it grew in the first place, if it is huge uncommitted transactions, then it may still grow, but if it was a record of many transactions over time, it may not grow.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to Q1: 
It is always a good idea to estimate your data growth and set an initial size for your database. The reason is simply to avoid the SQL Data file from performing Auto Growth operations which are very expensive. If you are not expecting any data growth, then whether or not you set Initial Size, it does not matter.

Answer to Q2:
You can send the Backup file to any location as long as your SQL Server version on which you restore the file is of similar or higher version. Only point to note is the data in the backup file - consider encryption if you have sensitive data.